# Is there a way to "turn off" a shared context inside a single blcok?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am using shared contexts to DRY my spec files.

However, I have one single `context` block where I would like to disable the shared context. Is this possible?

```rb
describe MyClass do
  include_context 'my shared context'

  describe '#some_method' do
    # Specs using the shared context...

    context 'with some special context' do
      # Turn off 'my shared context' here      
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not simply create another `RSpec.describe` block without including shared context? Would pretty explicit for other to understand a reason instead of diving into configuration to search why context not being loaded

Comment: That would be a good idea, but I have some setup in the `describe` block I want to use for all of the specs. Splitting it in two means I have to duplicate this setup.

Comment: you always can put shared setup into a method, class, module. This is ruby ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by slightly modifying how you include the context and using RSpec metadata, you should be able to get this working.

```
RSpec.shared_context "my shared context" do
  # code
end



# spec/support/shared_context_load.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before do |example|
    unless example.metadata[:load_shared_context] == false
      config.include_context "my shared context"
    end
  end
end



describe MyClass do
  # NOTE the shared_contxet is removed from here

  describe '#some_method' do
    # Specs using the shared context...

    it "this spec using shared context"
       # code
    end

    context 'with some special context' do
      it "this spec is not using shared context", load_shared_context: false do 
        # Turn off 'my shared context' here      
        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That sounds pretty neat. Can I do silly things like overriding that metadata in nested blocks? For instance, loading the context in one example inside the "with some special context" context?

Comment: @Richard-Degenne, you should be. Please note I have moved the metadata tag to `it` block. (previously it was in the wrong place). Since metadata runs for each spec ("it block"), you should be able to mix and match.